# Add platform device to kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I want to add a platform device file to my kernel (`arch/arm/plat-mxc/devices/platform-spi_imx.c`). Kernel 2.6.35, Freescale iMX53 processor. My device driver uses functions and structs defined in this platform file, however, I can't figure out how to get the file added to my kernel build. I tried adding the

```
CONFIG_
```

flag to my `.config` manually, but no luck.

Comment: Is this a third party module (or your own module) i.e. not part of the kernel that your distro provided? In that case, you don't add the module to the kernel tree, but you have to compile it using the `Makefile` provided, and then run `depmod` on the compiled module to add it to the kernel's list of modules.

Comment: The driver is my own and I've added it to the tree and it gets built as a module. This works okay. It's just that I need the platform device included as well as it defines some functions and structures I need.

Comment: I was talking about the platform device. I don't see it in the git tree on kernel.org at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/plat-mxc?h=v2.6.35 so it seems to be something that has been provided to you either by your distro or by the device vendor. They should have provided instructions to compile it as well.

Comment: Sounds like you are building "in tree" rather than as an external module ... and I presume you didn't mean `CONFIG_` literally but the `CONFIG_...` option that enables your platform device ... so check that the `Kconfig` and `Makefile` files are correct for your platform device file (look at the way it's done for others) and then add a dependency on it's config option into your driver's `Kconfig` file entry